# Utilities Sidebar not functioning properly

Tags: ios, xcode5

I have a XIB file inside of which there are some connections between some objects and the file's owner (a ViewController). I'm getting anything shown in the utilities sidebar that you can pop out from the sidebar in order to do some configuration stuff. It shows as **"Not Applicable"**. I had created the XIB file along with the ViewController file (check marked the option in the New File sheet) so the file's owner was preconfigured to the ViewController by default. I have already made the connections and added the necessary IBAction selector for the UIControl stuff. Its just that whenever i select an object in the view frame, its config doesn't show up in the utilities. **I have another XIB file hooked with some other view controller, and don't have the problem. What's up with Utilities sidebar????**

Answer (score 0):

I find restarting xCode often fixes this annoying bug.

Comment: i trashed the Xcode specific cache file and then restarted.Still not working

Comment: Did you stop xCode running in the toolbar ?

Comment: Yes.. I didn't  run the simulator in the first place. When I added a button to the view frame, all the the pre-existing objects in view frame plus the button itself  stopped showing config details in the inspector area. None of the inspectors(except for Quick-help) are showing anything but "Not Applicable" message in the center of the Utilities sidebar area.Worse still, when i run the simulator, the newly added button is not showing up in it.This is so frustrating.